# python numpy/scipy zoom changing center

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a 2D numpy array, say something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100, 100)
```

Now, I want to keep zoom this image (keeping the size the same i.e. (100, 100)) and I want to change the centre of the zoom.

So, say I want to zoom keeping the point `(70, 70)` at the centre and normally how one would do it is to "translate" the image to that point and then zoom.

I wonder how I can achieve this with `scipy`. I wonder if there is way to specify say 4 coordinates from this numpy array and basically fill the canvas with the interpolated image from this region of interest?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your question. It is unclear what you want to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ndimage.zoom to do the zooming part.  I use ndimage a lot, and it works well and is fast.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html

The 4 coordinates part you mention is I presume two corners of region you want to zoom into.  That's easy by just using numpy slicing of your image (presuming your image is an np array):

```
your_image[r1:r2, c1:c2]
```

Assuming you want your output image at 100x100, then your r1-r2, and c1-c2 differences will be the same, so your region is square.

nd.zoom takes a zoom factor (float).  You would need to compute whta athat zoom factor is in order to take your sliced image and turn it into a 100x100 sized array:

```
ndimage.zoom(your_image[r1:r2, c1:c2], zoom=your_zoom_factor)
```